# How can I shuffle a bidimensional array in VBscript?

Tags: sql, arrays, vbscript, asp-classic, shuffle

I need to shuffle a bidimensional array in vbscript, someone told me that I can use `newid()` in the sql query, but I'm not using sql server.
I'm seeing over the web something about `LBound` and `UBound`, but don't understand very much.
Can someone help me understand or tell me the best way to do it?
Thanks in advance. This is my code so far.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Questions"

recordset.Open sql, connection

If Not recordset.EOF Then
    nQuestions = recordset.RecordCount
    questions = recordset.GetRows(nQuestions, 0)
    If IsArray(questions) Then
    (...)
    End If
End If
```

Comment: So what DB are you using?

Comment: @Paul I'm using MS Access database

Answer (score 1):

To answer the part of your question relating to `UBound` and `LBound`:

`LBound` and `UBound` are the lower and upper bounds of the array. You specify two arguments, the array name and the dimension that you want to count, for instance:

```vbs
Dim myArr(10, 8)
Dim firstDim, secondDim
firstDim = UBound(myArr, 1)  ' The 1 here requests the size of the first dimension of the array
secondDim = UBound(myArr, 2) '... and this, the second.
```

Here, `firstDim` will hold the size of the first dimension of your array (i.e. 10), and `secondDim` the second (i.e. 8).

Obviously `LBound` works for the lowest dimension, though is only really used for arrays with a base other than the usual zero (possibly from COM objects).

**-- EDIT --**

To expand this further, you can get around this using a function in Access, but it does slow the process dramatically.

You'll need to create a query to select your data. Select the table that contains your questions. Drop all of the columns you need for your questions into the grid at the bottom.  In the `Field` box in the right most column of the grid type something like:

```
randomiser: Rnd([questionId])
```

(Obviously `questionId` being the unique id of the questions).

This will give you a list of questions with a random number (from 0 to 1) in the last column. Now change the sort order for this column to `Ascending`, and you can also add a `TOP` clause to the query to give you a specific number of questions.

Because an argument is specified for each row in the `Rnd` function it must execute every time, unlike simply putting `Rnd()`.  Notice, also, if you run the query and click into one of the randomised fields the number changes.

One thing to bear in mind here is that if you have an empty (NULL) value in one of the fields the sort will fail.